# How to Make the KeyBoard Disappear while using a UITextView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, objective-c-2.0

I am using a UITextView and I am confused about making the keyboard to disappear. Do I need to use some kind of a notification to make it disappear.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very intuitive, but all you have to do is implement the `doneButtonOnKeyboardPressed` event in your view controller. You don't actually have to do anything inside of the event handler, just handling it will cause the keyboard to disappear after the user taps "Done".

An empty handler will look something like this:

```
- (IBAction) doneButtonOnKeyboardPressed:(id)sender {  
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. It worked. You mentioned that it is not very intuitive. Can you please tell whether there is any other control I can use for multiple line input in iPhone. Thanks

Comment: Nope, this is pretty much what we're stuck with.  There's a lot about the iPhone SDK that isn't exactly intuitive.

Comment: A related question is: how do I get the "Done" key to appear on my keyboard? I don't appear to have one.

Comment: @musigenesis: Its a property of the UITextField, "Return key".

Comment: If I *just* add in that code the event doesn't get triggered. Guess I'm missing some connection between the GUI element I'm seeing, and the code I've written. To do the same thing with UITextField I can go look at the 'connections' panel and see the events available, including 'Did End On Exit'. I can then drag a connection onto the handling code. But UITextView doesn't show any 'Send Events'.